# How to create a plugin for "recording" web-scrape execution steps into a file?

Tags: plugins, browser, web-scraping, element

I am frequently tasked with the creation of web-scraping algorithms, and the way I have been doing it is directly to the scraping code, which makes each tool page-specific.

I'd like to create a plugin (preferably JavaScript) for the browser so that the user can define the scraping execution sequence dynamically (Record a script that will later be interpreted and executed for the actual scraping).

The idea is the following:

1. The user opens the page he wants to scrape, right clicks anywhere,
   and hits "starts recording", which "activates" the addon and saves
   the page's URL to it's "recording file".
2. For every element the user needs to click/type/change, he
   right-clicks it, and a set of element-specific options is shown. The
   addon saves these chosen options in order.

---

- Buttons can be clicked.
- Edits can be filled with a single specific string, or loop-scraped
  with a list of strings from a file.
- Lists can be loop-scraped for each of the items in them or for items
  that match a list from a file.
- Etc...

---

When recording is done, the user simply right-clicks anywhere and hits "stop recording", and he will have a script-like file containing the needed scraping actions.

After that, the actual scraping application takes over (automatically or manually started), and just reads the file that was recorded, executes the actions described and saves the resulting page.

These resulting pages can later be parsed by an easier-coded page-specific algorithm.

---

I know it's easier said than done, but I am pretty sure it's possible to code. I'd like some help figuring the "substeps":

- "How to display a new option in the browser's (+element's)
  context-menu?"
- "How to know what element was right-clicked?"
- "How to write a file from an addon?"
- Etc...

Although some of these questions have already been asked before, most of them are on a different context; Namely, a context in which you already know what element that was clicked, and wants to execute a function after it's clicked; Not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually been working on a Greasemonkey script to do that in the last days:

It works as follow

1. Inject a "scraping interface" in the page
2. Register an mouseup listener to the document
3. Extract the selection of the user, when the mouse up event occurs, and mark the selection as data-to-scrape
4. Insert divs/classes in the page to highlight the data-to-scrape
5. Store all scraping instructions / visited pages with GM_setValue
6. Display a scraping script in a textarea, so he user can copy/paste it to the scraping application

Comment: So, how is a scraping-interface done? I already understand the super-steps needed, but how do I do the sub-steps within them?

Comment: The substeps depend a lot on how you want it to look, and a little bit on what you expect to scrap. With greasemonkey you can just use basic Javascript: E.g. my "scraping interface" is not much more than a div with position: fixed, some <input> options and a <textarea> for output. $(document),mouseup with jquery catches all mouse clicks and window.getSelection() returns the selection...